# Retrieve custom fields from parent table and and some other custom fields from child models using with in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i'm having the following issue on a projetct, i'm trying to retrieve some fields from a model and other specific fields from a child relationship, but when i use the `->select('id')` statement, it just retrieve the `id` field from my parent model and all child relationships comes as null values, for example:

```
$someData = App\Book::with(['author:id,name,email', 'publisher:id,name,address'])->select('id')->get();
```

I just want to retrieve the book **id**; the author **id, name and email** fields and finally **'id, name and address'**  fields from the publisher table, this is clear?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform a `->select('id')`, Laravel does not have the foreign key that it needs for the relationships.

Simply add the foreign key to the select:

```
->select('id', 'author_id', 'publisher_id')
```

So it should look like this:

```
$someData = App\Book::with(['author:id,name,email', 'publisher:id,name,address'])
    ->select('id', 'author_id', 'publisher_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: i have been searching for this long time

Comment: @ThauanCSantos No problem :)